# imagens escapando da coluna

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Eu estou tendo problemas com um grid de imagens que em resoluções menores ficam uma sobre a outra como camadas e em resolução maiores elas ficam com uma espaço muito grande entre elas.

As colunas são geradas dinamicamente por isso não posso colocar uma row na segunda linha, no exemplo eu fiz de forma estática imagem por imagem.

o `max-width` com `!important`esta ali pra tratar quando a imagem não vem quadrada como a quarta imagem. Pode acontecer alguns casos de chegar em uma resolução igual da quarta imagem.

obs: Para ver os espaços ver em "Página toda"

```css
img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 324px !important;
    max-height: 324px;
    object-fit: cover;
  }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section section-sm">

  <div class="container-fluid clearfix d-flex">

    <div class="row list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center" *ngIf="grid">
      <!-- A view wtih big Photos and no text -->
      <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/480x600" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-6" >
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Cara se a imagem tem no máximo 324px de largura ela não vai passar disso... como vc espera que ela se comporte? Ocupando todo o espaço da `col` ?

Comment: @hugocsl eu quero que ela tenha no max 324px mas quando está em resolução menor ela não acompanha a div ficando uma por cima da outra. Se eu tiro esse max ela funciona com as a maioria das imagens mas essa imagem com resolução diferente fica maior que as outras.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vc tem alguns problemas no seu código, primeiro que no BS 4 não existe `col-xs-6`, se vc quer que cada coluna tenha 50% de largura em telas pequenas basta colocar `col-6` no lugar de `xs-6`.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Outro problema é que vc colocou um `width` máximo com `max-width`, por isso elas encavalam uma na outra, vc tem que declarar além do `max-width` tb o `width:100%` Assim quando o container tiver menos de 324px a imagem ocupa 100% do container entende...

Uma dica sobre a imagem no formato diferente das outras o ideal é que vc coloque o tamanho em um container e não diretamente na imagem, assim o container fica com o tamanho que vc quer, e a imagem dentro dele fica com 100% de altura e largura...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 324px !important;
    max-height: 324px !important;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid red !important;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section section-sm">

  <div class="container-fluid clearfix d-flex">

    <div class="row list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center" *ngIf="grid">
      <!-- A view wtih big Photos and no text -->
      <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/480x600" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 " >
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

**Tratando a imagem mais alta**

Uma opção para *corrigir* o problema da imagem mais alta é colocar `d-flex`, tb nos container pai, como no `link` e na própria `col`

Repare na imagem abaixo que agora todos as imagens da mesma coluna seguem a altura do maior item

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.8.2/css/all.min.css" />
<style>
    img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 324px !important;
    max-height: 324px !important;
    object-fit: cover;
    border: 2px solid red !important;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>
  

<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<section class="section section-sm">

  <div class="container-fluid clearfix d-flex">

    <div class="row list-inline mx-auto justify-content-center" *ngIf="grid">
      <!-- A view wtih big Photos and no text -->
      <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/480x600" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
            <div class="p-0 col-6 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 d-flex justify-content-center ">
        <div class="photoContainer d-flex justify-content-center">
          <a href="#" target="_blank" class="d-flex " >
            <img class="img-fluid" src="https://via.placeholder.com/640x640" >
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
  
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Obrigado, Hugo entendi o problema agr e consegui resolver com sua ajuda.

Comment: @GiovanniDias legal que deu certo ai, sucesso

Answer (score -2):

Você pode usar `display:grid` no `.photocontainer` e na `img` usar `object-fit: cover`:

```css
/* The parent container */
.photocontainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Respondi do celular, vim aqui reformatar e recebi downvote? Sério isso?

Comment: Cara se vc respondeu pelo cel talvez vc não tenha testado seu código... ele ficou como na imagem http://prntscr.com/ofw5iz ... ele não respeita os tamanho máximos definidos para a imagem e a imagem que é maior fica bem diferente das outras... Nem foi eu que te negativei, mas veja que a resposta resolve um problema, mas gera outros colaterais etc... OBS: se meu monitor fosse maior as imagens continuariam a crescer, pois o max é 1fr, ou seja se meu monitor tiver 4000px de largura cada imagem teria 1000px de largura

Comment: Ah entendi, faz sentido. Valeu!